# Rigidbody.MoveRotation: multiplying quaternions causes constant rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

```
Quaternion q1 = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.Cross(transform.right, normal), normal);
Quaternion q2 = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - transform.position, normal);
```

I'm trying to rotate and object in a 3D scene using two Quaternions together so that the object remains perpendicular to the terrain below it (q1) and the front of the object faces a target transform (q2);

In `FixedUpdate` using `Rigidbody.MoveRotation(q1)` or `Rigidbody.MoveRotation(q2)` causes an object to rotate to the required rotation and stay pointing in that direction. If I use `Rigidbody.MoveRotation(q1 * q2)` it spins round and round on its up axis.

I've tried everything I can think of to generate q1 and q2 and regardless of how I come up with those angles its multiplying them together that causes the spinning problem.

Do we need to cache some kind of rotation delta or something to track how far its rotated since last frame & adjust?

Cross posted on [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/172716/rigidbody-moverotation-multiplying-quaternions-causes-constant-rotation).

Comment: did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer which did make sense but was not really related to the problem, in hindsight I could have explained better. In conclusion you cant calculate a new angle every frame, that adds additional rotation; best to calculate the desired rotation at periodic intervals and lerp to / coroutine.

Answer (score 1):

The quaternions produced by `LookRotation` are each such that rotate *from the identity rotation* to the rotation that the parameters specify. Applying the second rotation from a non-identity rotation (which is what `q1 * q2` does) may make it fail to meet one or both of the `LookRotation` parameters that `q2` was created with.

Use [`Vector3.OrthoNormalize`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.OrthoNormalize.html) to find the vector orthogonal to `normal` that is closest to `target.position - transform.position`. You'll have to handle the situation where normal and that direction are parallel.

Then, use [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to get the rotation that will point a transform's `forward` and `up` in those directions:

```
Vector lookDirection = target.position - transform.position;
if (Mathf.Approximately(1f, Vector3.Dot(normal, lookDirection)))
{
    // normal and lookDirection are parallel
    // Do something reasonable about look direction here.
    // That may mean doing nothing at all!
    return;
}


Vector3.OrthoNormalize(ref normal, ref lookDirection);
Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookDirection, normal);

Rigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
```

An alternative is to use `LookRotation` to look in the `normal` direction and have up as close to pointing away from target.position as possible first, then pitch downwards 90 degrees:

```
Vector lookDirection = target.position - transform.position;
if (Mathf.Approximately(1f, Vector3.Dot(normal, lookDirection)))
{
    // normal and lookDirection are parallel
    // Do something reasonable about look direction here.
    // That may mean doing nothing at all!
    return;
}

Quaternion bottomTowardsTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(normal, -lookDirection);
Quaternion newRotation = bottomTowardsTarget * Quaternion.Euler(-90f,0,0);

Rigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
```